# Swift: What does an ! next to function name mean?

Tags: swift

I came across this piece of code today:

```
object.myFunction!(parameterOne, paramenterTwo)
```

I'm used to seeing `myFunction()!`

It force unwraps an optional returned by myFunction.

But what does `myFunction!()` mean?

Comment: It's an optional closure property. That `!` may cause a crash like many uses of `!`.

Comment: In this case `myFunction` is optional itself. You try to unwrapp `myFunction` and not the result. By the way "myFunction" is a bad name, it is more "myClosure" in your case

Answer (score 2):

This would appear typically because `myFunction` is an optional protocol method.

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    @objc optional func myFunction()
}
```

The compiler doesn't know whether the protocol adopter (`object`) implements `myFunction`, because it is optional. The exclamation mark claims that you know it *does* implement it. If you're wrong, you'll crash.